# how to highlight the searched/filtered text in android?

Tags: android, searchview

Filtering the text is working fine but now my requirement is to highlight the filtered text with some colour.How to implement this in my code

The code goes like this:
The filter method which is in the adapter class:

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ContestHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
List<Student_model> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<Student_model> templist;
int expandedPosition = -1;
int prev = -2;
Context context;
student_fragment student_fragment;
Student_model contest;
String url = "http://labsls.com/drill/index.php/questionpool/deleteusers";

public class ContestHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, sub, school, name, password, username, email, phonenum, stdlvl, std, scl;
    public RelativeLayout details, titlebar;
    public Button update, home;
    public ImageView image, tick;
    EditText stdnmedi, useredi, passwordedi, emailedi, phoneedi, stndrdedi, schooledi;

    public ContestHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.studenttitle);
        sub = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.standardsub);
        std = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.std);
        scl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.skool);
        home = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.homebt);
        details = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.detials);
        titlebar = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.titlebar);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stdname);
        stdnmedi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.namedi);
        useredi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ediuser);
        update = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.updatebt);
        passwordedi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.passuser);
        emailedi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ediemail);
        phoneedi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ediphone);
        stndrdedi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edistd);
        schooledi = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edischoolz);
        tick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgtic);
    }
}

public StudentAdapter(Context context, List<Student_model> data, student_fragment student) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.student_fragment = student;
    this.templist = new ArrayList<>(data);
}

@Override
public ContestHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_list, parent, false);
    ContestHolder holder = new ContestHolder(v);
    holder.titlebar.setOnClickListener(StudentAdapter.this);
    holder.titlebar.setTag(holder);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContestHolder holder, final int position) {
    contest = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(contest.getTitle());
    holder.std.setText(" " + contest.getStdlevel());
    holder.scl.setText(" " + contest.getSchool());
    holder.stdnmedi.setText(contest.getTitle());
    holder.useredi.setText(contest.getUsername());
    holder.phoneedi.setText(contest.getPhonenum());
    holder.passwordedi.setText(contest.getPassword());
    holder.emailedi.setText(contest.getEmail());
    holder.stndrdedi.setText(contest.getStdlevel());
    holder.schooledi.setText(contest.getSchool());
    holder.home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Landing.class));
        }
    });
    holder.titlebar.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            data.get(position).setSelect(!data.get(position).isSelect());
            holder.tick.setVisibility(data.get(position).isSelect() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            showremove();
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String ur = "http://labsls.com/drill/index.php/questionpool/updateuserdetails";
            StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ur, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("testup", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("response");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject Objectz = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String namee = Objectz.getString("fullname");
                            holder.stdnmedi.setText(namee);
                            String usere = Objectz.getString("username");
                            holder.useredi.setText(usere);
                            String passe = Objectz.getString("password");
                            holder.passwordedi.setText(passe);
                            String emaile = Objectz.getString("email_id");
                            holder.emailedi.setText(emaile);
                            String phonee = Objectz.getString("mobile");
                            holder.phoneedi.setText(phonee);
                            String stlvle = Objectz.getString("standardlevel");
                            holder.stndrdedi.setText(stlvle);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //  params.put("nAme",holder.stdnmedi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("uName", holder.useredi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("pAwd", holder.passwordedi.getText().toString());
                    //  params.put("eMail",holder.emailedi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("mobile", holder.phoneedi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("school", holder.schooledi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("standardlevel", holder.stndrdedi.getText().toString());
                    params.put("uID", contest.getUseruniq());
                    return params;
                }
            };
            stringrequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            requestQueue.add(stringrequest);
            Toast.makeText(context, holder.stdnmedi.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    if (position == expandedPosition) {
        holder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void filter(String query) {
    data.clear();
    Log.d("Test", "1");
    if (query.length() == 0) {
        data.addAll(templist);
    } else {
        String filterPattern = query.toLowerCase().trim();
        for (Student_model app : templist) {
            if (app.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                data.add(app);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

The class in which the filter method in the adapter class is being called:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: add complete code of `Adapter` to your question

Comment: added the complete code @K2evil

Comment: Ok... Now which `TextView`s do you want to change color?

Comment: The textview named title@K2evil

Answer (score 2):

```
1. in StudentAdapter create global variable;
   String searchString="";
2. in method filter(String query), asign searchString=query;
3. in onBindViewHolder() method, put below code.



SpannableString spannableStringSearch = null;

if ((searchString!= null) && (!searchString.isEmpty())) {        
      spannableStringSearch = new SpannableString(contest.getTitle());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contest.getTitle());
    while (matcher.find()) {
            spannableStringSearch.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)),
            matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
if(spannableStringSearch !=null){
    holder.title.setText(spannableStringSearch);
}
else{
   holder.title.setText(spannableStringSearch);
}
```

Comment: could you please explain this code in relation with my code

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (1 ... 1) ends beyond length 0...the app crashes and is displaying this error @Firzan Ghulam

Comment: Now the error is gone and the searching is taking place but still the colour is not changing @Firzan Ghulam

Comment: `else` case should have `searchString` instead of `spannableStringSearch` since you have already checked `spannableStringSearch` is null and setText with null argument is not expected behaviour and can lead to unexpected outcomes.